# Conditional partials when using Rails STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, partials, sti

I have a clients table with 2 types: person and company.
I want to be able to render a different partial (with different no. of fields) depending on what type of client I'm creating.

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can compare type attribute values and render needed partial. Or use different controllers and views for this two models

Comment: Yeah, but I wanna do this for new forms, so I'm thinking there's no way to know the type yet. I am having 2 different routes for the types though.

Comment: @BogdanPopa And what's the problem ? On object initialization you should have type value.

Comment: @BogdanPopa Only if you init object on Person or Company model. If you init object on Client model the type will be nil

Answer (score 0):

You should have two links, Create Person and Create Company. When clicking Create Person, you can can still hit the `new` page, and just have a parameter like `type=person` (i.e, `new_client_path(:type => "person")`). Do the reverse for the company.

In your controller, switch between each one to create the initial, empty Object. If there is no `type` param, or it's invalid, make the type `person` by default and just continue on as normal.

On your `new` page, you can have a big `if-else` to figure out what form fields to show. Or better yet, have two partials, one named something like `_person_form` and the other like `_company_form`. Then in your `new` page just do something like `render :partial => "#{@client.type}_form"` so you'll get the correct form.